# Space Replacement for Float/Int/Double

Tags: java, floating-point

I am working on a class assignment this morning and I want to try and solve a problem I have noticed in all of my team mates programs so far; the fact that spaces in an int/float/double cause Java to freak out.

To solve this issue I had a very crazy idea but it does work under certain circumstances.  However the problem is that is does not always work and I cannot figure out why.  Here is my "main" method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    //needed for scanner class

public class Test2
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

      BugChecking bc = new BugChecking();
      String i;
      double i2 = 0;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);   

      System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");

      while (i2 <= 0.0)
      {
             i = in.nextLine();

             i = bc.deleteSpaces(i);  

            //cast back to float
            i2 = Double.parseDouble(i);

            if (i2 <= 0.0)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0.");
            }
      }

      in.close();
      System.out.println(i2);       
 }
}
```

So here is the class, note that I am working with floats but I made it so that it can be used for any type so long as it can be cast to a string:

```
public class BugChecking
{
    BugChecking()
    {

    }

    public String deleteSpaces(String s)
    {  

        //convert string into a char array
        char[] cArray = s.toCharArray();

        //now use for loop to find and remove spaces
        for (i3 = 0; i3 < cArray.length; i3++)
        {
            if ((Character.isWhitespace(cArray[i3])) && (i3 != cArray.length)) //If current element contains a space remove it via overwrite
            {
                for (i4 = i3; i4 < cArray.length-1;i4++)
                {
                    //move array elements over by one element
                    storage1 = cArray[i4+1];
                    cArray[i4] = storage1;                  
                }
            }
        }

        s = new String(cArray);

        return s; 
    }  

    int i3; //for iteration
    int i4; //for iteration
    char storage1; //for storage
}
```

Now, the goal is to remove spaces from the array in order to fix the problem stated at the beginning of the post and from what I can tell this code should achieve that and it does, but only when the first character of an input is the space.

For example, if I input " 2.0332" the output is "2.0332".

However if I input "2.03 445 " the output is "2.03" and the rest gets lost somewhere.

This second example is what I am trying to figure out how to fix.

EDIT:

David's suggestion below was able to fix the problem.  Bypassed sending an int.  Send it directly as a string then convert (I always heard this described as casting) to desired variable type.  Corrected code put in place above in the Main method.

A little side note, if you plan on using this even though replace is much easier, be sure to add an && check to the if statement in deleteSpaces to make sure that the if statement only executes if you are not on the final array element of cArray.  If you pass the last element value via i3 to the next for loop which sets i4 to the value of i3 it will trigger an OutOfBounds error I think since it will only check up to the last element - 1.

Comment: I took your method (there are simpler ways of doing this, but that's beside the point), then I input "2.03 445" and it seems to work. Did you check that you are passing the right arguments to your method? Adding logging may be.

Comment: I don't get it. To replace all spaces just use `s.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: I guess you are calling a main(String[] args) method? Then spaces will separate the arguments you give to your program. So when you do `java MyNumberConverter 22.2 33`, your main method is called getting the arguments "22.2" and "33".

Comment: @mprivat check my post again, I added the method that calls the deleteSpaces method for further explanation.  This is part of a separate class that gets called from the main execution function.  A float value is passed to the checkFloat method where it is cast to a string.

Comment: @TimBüthe This still results in 2.03 when used with 2.03 445.  I am using Eclipse to write this program, could have be having some affect on the output?  Or maybe the way I am casting the data is?

Comment: @Geowil check my answer, I think you main method doesn't handle the arguments right. Besides, you should read up on casting, you don't cast anything in your code.

Comment: @mprivat Interesting.  Added some break points and tracked it.  If there is a space after the first character Eclipse or Java seems to truncate the input.  I will try running my program from the command prompt and see if it is any different.

Comment: @TimBüthe Included my main method so you get a better idea of where the program is coming from.  I also posted up all of the bugChecking class as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to get rid of all white spaces inbetween a `String` use [`replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
    String sBefore = "2.03 445 ";

    String sAfter = sBefore.replaceAll("\\s+", "");//replace white space and tabs
    //String sAfter = sBefore.replace(' ', '');//replace white space only
    double i = 0;

    try {
        i = Double.parseDouble(sAfter);//parse to integer
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(i);//2.03445
```

**UPDATE:**

Looking at your code snippet the problem might be that you read it directly as a float/int/double (thus entering a whitespace stops the `nextFloat()`) rather read the input as a `String` using `nextLine()`, delete the white spaces then attempt to convert it to the appropriate format.

This seems to work fine for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //bugChecking bc = new bugChecking();
    float i = 0.0f;
    String tmp = "";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer");

    while (true) {

        tmp = in.nextLine();//read line
        tmp = tmp.replaceAll("\\s+", "");//get rid of spaces

        if (tmp.isEmpty()) {//wrong input
            System.err.println("Please enter a number greater than 0.");
        } else {//correct input

            try{//attempt to convert sring to float
            i = new Float(tmp);
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {    
                System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
            }

            System.out.println(i);
            break;//got correct input halt loop
        }

    }
    in.close();
}
```

**EDIT:**

as a side note please start all class names with a capital letter i.e `bugChecking` class should be `BugChecking` the same applies for `test2` class it should be `Test2`

Comment: Heads up, `replaceAll` takes a RegEx as fist parameter. You could use `replace` to search and replcae Strings, or use a regex that finds whitespace (spaces as well as tabs), like this `.replaceAll("\\s+","");`

Comment: @TimBüthe Same result with replace.All.  still just 2.03 instead of the full 2.03445.  I am beginning to think Eclipse is doing something wrong with the code.

Comment: @Geowil if you copy and paste my snippet does it work? if yes then I'd suggest a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to demonstrate the problem. Have a look at Tims answer too that might be the problem. +1 to him

Comment: @DavidKroukamp See my edited code in the main method.  Added the changes you suggested and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp edited the code to your suggestions and I removed and added a few things that were not/were needed.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`String` objects have methods on them that allow you to do this kind of thing. The one you want in particular is [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29). This pretty much does what you're trying to do for you.

```
String input = " 2.03 445 ";
input = input.replace(" ", ""); // "2.03445"
```

You could also use regular expressions to replace more than just spaces. For example, to get rid of everything that isn't a digit or a period:

```
String input = "123,232 . 03 445 ";
input = input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""); // "123232.03445"
```

This will replace any non-digit, non-period character so that you're left with only those characters in the input. See the javadocs for [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn a bit about regular expressions, or search for one of the many tutorials available online.

**Edit:** One other remark, [`String.trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) will remove all whitespace from the beginning and end of your string to turn `" 2.0332"` into `"2.0332"`:

```
String input = " 2.0332 ";
input = input.trim(); // "2.0332"
```

**Edit 2:** With your update, I see the problem now. `Scanner.nextFloat` is what's breaking on the space. If you change your code to use `Scanner.nextLine` like so:

```
while (i <= 0) {
    String input = in.nextLine();
    input = input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
    float i = Float.parseFloat(input);

    if (i <= 0.0f) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0.");
    }

    System.out.println(i);        
}
```

That code will properly accept you entering things like `"123,232 . 03 445"`. Use any of the solutions in place of my `replaceAll` and it will work.

`Scanner.nextFloat` will split your input automatically based on whitespace. `Scanner` can take a delimiter when you construct it (for example, `new Scanner(System.in, ",./ ")` will delimit on `,`, `.`, `/`, and )" The default constructor, `new Scanner(System.in)`, automatically delimits based on whitespace.

Comment: Brian, I tried this but got the same result as me second example in my original post.  Maybe it is some issue with Eclipse (it is the IDE am using at the moment)?

Comment: How are you passing the input to your program?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp ... I said that: "from the beginning and end of your string". I figured since he originally wrote this code to trim the string, I would also point at that Java can do this for him as well. It's not a solution to his problem, hence I called it a "remark."

Comment: +1 sorry never saw that but it doesnt help the OP as this is the `String` he shows as an example:  "2.03 445 " which means you'd have tp call `trim()` and `replace()`. Not very efficient IMO

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using the first argument from you main method. If you main method looks somehow like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(deleteSpaces(args[0]);
}
```

Your problem is, that spaces separate the arguments that get handed to your main method. So running you class like this:

```
java MyNumberConverter 22.2 33
```

The first argument arg[0] is "22.2" and the second arg[1] "33"

But like other have suggested, [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) is a better way of doing this anyway.

Comment: `java MyNumberConverter "22.2 33"` would solve the separate args issue.